# One to One chat application in xamarin.forms using pubnub

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, pubnub

I would like to create one to one chat application using xamarin forms, i have created group chat by using my keys,What exactly i want is,i will get list of people who are subscribed to my channel for example a,b,c,so when i click on a ,my messages should only read by a but not by b and c.so dynamically the channel has to be created between me and a,how to create one to one channels dynamically in xamarin,forms using pubnub.

Comment: Your question is not so much specific to Xamarin Forms but is just a common design pattern that most chat apps need to incorporate. [This blog is old and JavaScript based but should provide insights](https://www.pubnub.com/blog/2014-08-20-create-private-chat-demand-connecting-users/). For further discussion, I recommend opening up a private support case with [PubNub Support](https://support.pubnub.com) and we can post back any solutions on this thread.

Comment: Our [Chat Fundamentals guide](https://www.pubnub.com/docs/web-javascript/chat-fundamentals) is also very informative for an overall chat best practices & design patterns angle. Also JS based but the basic architecture is the same on any platform.

Answer (score 0):

Our [Chat Fundamentals guide](https://www.pubnub.com/blog/2014-08-20-create-private-chat-demand-connecting-users/) is also very informative for an overall chat best practices & design patterns angle. Also JS based but the basic architecture is the same on any platform.

But basically, there is nothing to creating channels for two users to chat. Just decide how you will dynamically generate the channel name and have both clients subscribe to the channel. A very simple channel naming convention for two users to chat would be using the usernames like,  ch_usera_userb.

Comment: If it is an option, check out [PubNub ChatEngine](https://www.pubnub.com/products/chatengine/) which will facilitate much of what you want to do.